# Changing Selected Radio Button With JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have an MVC project, and in a particular page, I have a form that allows a user to create a question for a test.  There is a textarea field for the question text, and 4 textarea fields for answers, as well as checkboxes for "All Of The Above" and "None Of The Above".  There are also radio buttons for each potential answer that allow for the user to select which answer is the correct one.  If the user chooses to add "All Of The Above" as an option, then the checkbox and radio button for "None Of The Above" and the textarea and radio button for Answer 4 are all disabled.  If "None Of The Above" is selected, then the same thing happens, except with "All Of The Above" and Answer 4.  All of this works correctly.

The problem is that a radio button that is selected is disabled, it stays disabled, and I want that radio button to be disabled and the radio button corresponding to the checked checkbox to be selected.  I have tried various methods of accomplishing this, but none of them has worked.  Most recently, I have tried to use the value for the radio button group to fix determine which radio buttons to select and deselect.

I know it's lengthy, but I'm including the code for the entire page, which includes both the HTML and JQuery.

```
@using WebContentDemo.Helpers;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add A Question To Test";
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("AddQuestion", "Test", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                <div class="panel @Utilities.PanelColor()">
                    <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                        <h2 style="margin-top:1px;margin-bottom:1px;">@ViewBag.Title </h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body text-center" style="padding-left:15px;padding-right:15px;">

                        <div class="row" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <p>
                                    Type in the question text for this question in the text field to the right. After that, you can
                                    type in the text for up to four answers. If you choose to make one of the possible answers "All Of The Above"
                                    or "None Of The Above", the option that you do not choose, and the fourth answer text field will be disabled.
                                </p>
                                <p>
                                    Ensure that you mark the correct answer with the radio button
                                    (<input type="radio" disabled="disabled" style="cursor:default" />) next to the that answer. By default, the
                                    radio button for the first answer will be selected, so you could also simply make sure to always type the
                                    correct answer into that field.
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                                <label for="QuestionText">Question Text</label>
                                <textarea class="form-control" id="QuestionText" placeholder="Question Text" autofocus="autofocus" rows="6" type="text" style="max-width:100%;width:100%" required="required" name="QuestionText"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr />
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="panel @Utilities.PanelColor()">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                                        <label for="Answer_1">First Answer</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="Answer_1" placeholder="First Answer" style="max-width:100%;width:100%;" rows="4" required="required" name="Answer_1"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-footer">
                                        <label for="Answer_1_Radio">This Is The Correct Answer</label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="Answer_1_Radio" class="form_radio" checked="checked" name="CorrectAnswer" value="Answer_1" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="panel @Utilities.PanelColor()">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                                        <label for="Answer_2">Second Answer</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="Answer_2" placeholder="Second Answer" style="max-width:100%;width:100%;" rows="4" required="required" name="Answer_2"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-footer">
                                        <label for="Answer_2_Radio">This Is The Correct Answer</label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="Answer_2_Radio" class="form_radio" name="CorrectAnswer" value="Answer_2" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="panel @Utilities.PanelColor()">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                                        <label for="Answer_3">Third Answer</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="Answer_3" placeholder="Third Answer" style="max-width:100%;width:100%;" rows="4" required="required" name="Answer_3"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-footer">
                                        <label for="Answer_3_Radio">This Is The Correct Answer</label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="Answer_3_Radio" class="form_radio" name="CorrectAnswer" value="Answer_3" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="max-height:100%;height:100%;">
                                <div class="panel @Utilities.PanelColor()">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                                        <label>Other</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body" style="max-height:100%;height:100%;">
                                        <label for="AllOfTheAbove">All Of The Above</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="true" id="AllOfTheAbove" name="AllOfTheAbove" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-footer">
                                        <label for="AllOfTheAbove_Radio">This Is The Correct Answer</label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="AllOfTheAbove_Radio" class="form_radio" name="CorrectAnswer" value="AllOfTheAbove" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4" style="max-height:100%;height:100%;">
                                <div class="panel @Utilities.PanelColor()">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                                        <label>Other</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body" style="max-height:100%;height:100%;">
                                        <label for="NoneOfTheAbove">None Of The Above</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" value="true" id="NoneOfTheAbove" name="NoneOfTheAbove" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-footer">
                                        <label for="NoneOfTheAbove_Radio">This Is The Correct Answer</label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="NoneOfTheAbove_Radio" class="form_radio" name="CorrectAnswer" value="NoneOfTheAbove" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="panel @Utilities.PanelColor()">
                                    <div class="panel-heading" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;">
                                        <label for="Answer_4">Fourth Answer</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-body">
                                        <textarea class="form-control" id="Answer_4" placeholder="Third Answer" style="max-width:100%;width:100%;" rows="4" required="required" name="Answer_3"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="panel-footer">
                                        <label for="Answer_4_Radio">This Is The Correct Answer</label>
                                        <input type="radio" id="Answer_4_Radio" class="form_radio" name="CorrectAnswer" value="Answer_4" />
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                                <label for="AddAnother">Add Another Question?</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" value="true" id="AddAnother" name="AddAnother" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                                <input style="max-width:100%;width:100%;" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Add This Question" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#AllOfTheAbove').click(function () {
            if ($('#AllOfTheAbove').is(':checked')) {
                $('#Answer_4').prop("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#NoneOfTheAbove').prop("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio').prop("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#Answer_4_Radio').prop("disabled", "disabled");
                if ($('.form_radio').val() == "NoneOfTheAbove") {
                    $('#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio').removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#AllOfTheAbove_Radio').prop("checked", "checked");
                }
                if ($('.form_radio').val() == "Answer_4") {
                    $('#Answer_4').removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#AllOfTheAbove_Radio').prop("checked", "checked");
                }
            }
            else if ($('#AllOfTheAbove').not(':checked')) {
                $('#Answer_4').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#NoneOfTheAbove').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#Answer_4_Radio').removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
        $('#NoneOfTheAbove').click(function () {
            if ($('#NoneOfTheAbove').is(':checked')) {
                $('#Answer_4').prop("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#AllOfTheAbove').prop("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#AllOfTheAbove_Radio').prop("disabled", "disabled");
                $('#Answer_4_Radio').prop("disabled", "disabled");
                if ($('.form_radio').val() == "AllOfTheAbove") {
                    $('#AllOfTheAbove_Radio').removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio').prop("checked", "checked");
                }
                if ($('.form_radio').val() == "Answer_4") {
                    $('#Answer_4').removeAttr("checked");
                    $('#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio').prop("checked", "checked");
                }
            }
            else if ($('#AllOfTheAbove').not(':checked')) {
                $('#Answer_4').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#AllOfTheAbove').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#AllOfTheAbove_Radio').removeAttr("disabled");
                $('#Answer_4_Radio').removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have understood your question, you want to disable other correct answer options when either of the check boxes are clicked.  I copied the following from other answer on SO..

Why use prop() when you could use attr()/removeAttr() to do this?
Basically, prop() should be used when getting or setting properties (such as autoplay, checked,  disabled and required amongst others).

By using removeAttr(), you are completely removing the disabled attribute itself - while prop() is merely setting the property's underlying boolean value to false.

While what you want to do can be done using attr()/removeAttr(), it doesn't mean it should be done (and can cause strange/problematic behaviour, as in this case).

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#AllOfTheAbove').click(function () {
        if ($('#AllOfTheAbove').is(':checked')) {
            console.log("All checked");
            $('input:radio[name=CorrectAnswer]').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', false); }); //uncheck all first..
            //$('input:radio[name=CorrectAnswer]').each(function () { $(this).prop('disabled', true); }); //disable all                
            $("#Answer_4_Radio").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#NoneOfTheAbove").prop('checked', false);

            $('#AllOfTheAbove_Radio').prop("checked", true);
            $('#AllOfTheAbove_Radio').prop("disabled", false);
        }
        else if ($('#AllOfTheAbove').not(':checked')) {
            console.log("All un checked");
            $('input:radio[name=CorrectAnswer]').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', false); }); //uncheck all first..
            $('input:radio[name=CorrectAnswer]').each(function () { $(this).prop('disabled', false); }); //enable all   
        }
    });
    $('#NoneOfTheAbove').click(function () {
        if ($('#NoneOfTheAbove').is(':checked')) {
            console.log("None checked");
            $('input:radio[name=CorrectAnswer]').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', false); }); //uncheck all first..
            //$('input:radio[name=CorrectAnswer]').each(function () { $(this).prop('disabled', true); }); //disable all
            $("#Answer_4_Radio").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#AllOfTheAbove_Radio").prop('disabled', true);
            $("#AllOfTheAbove").prop('checked', false);

            $('#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio').prop("checked", true);
            $('#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio').prop("disabled", false); 
        }
        else if ($('#AllOfTheAbove').not(':checked')) {
            console.log("None un checked");
            $('input:radio[name=CorrectAnswer]').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', false); }); //uncheck all first..
            $('input:radio[name=CorrectAnswer]').each(function () { $(this).prop('disabled', false); }); //enable all                 
        }
    });

    $('#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio').click(function () {
        if ($('#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio').is(':checked')) {  
            $("#NoneOfTheAbove").prop("checked", true);
            $("#AllOfTheAbove").prop("checked", false);
        }
    });

    $('#AllOfTheAbove_Radio').click(function () {
        if ($('#AllOfTheAbove_Radio').is(':checked')) {  
            $("#AllOfTheAbove").prop("checked", true);
            $("#NoneOfTheAbove").prop("checked", false);
        }
    });        
</script>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: This is almost perfect. The only problem is that when the "All Of The Above" checkbox is checked, I don't want to disable **ALL** of the other radio buttons, just the ones for Answer 4 and "None Of The Above".  When the "None Of The Above" checkbox is checked, the radio buttons for Answer 4 and "All Of The Above" should be disabled. Also, if one of the radio buttons that gets disabled is checked when it is disabled, I want that radio button to get unchecked, and the radio button for the corresponding checked checkbox gets checked. I'm going to fool around with your code and see if I can do it.

Comment: If you get the code to do this before I do, that would be great, but probably not required. I might get it to work myself, I just don't really like JavaScript. At all.  Also, I used prop() because I was borrowing the method from another Stack Overflow post about an unrelated issue.

Comment: Edited the answer ... Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to make a few modifications to T. Shah's code to get it to function exactly as I wanted.  Here is what I did.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#AllOfTheAbove').click(function () {
    if ($('#AllOfTheAbove').is(':checked')) {
        console.log("All checked");
        $('input:radio[name=CorrectAnswer]').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', false); }); //uncheck all first..
        $("#Answer_4_Radio").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#NoneOfTheAbove").prop('checked', false);
        $("#Answer_4").prop('disabled', true);
        $('#AllOfTheAbove_Radio').prop("checked", true);
        $('#AllOfTheAbove_Radio').prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else if ($('#AllOfTheAbove').not(':checked')) {
        console.log("All un checked");
        $('input:radio[name=CorrectAnswer]').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', false); }); //uncheck all first..
        $('input:radio[name=CorrectAnswer]').each(function () { $(this).prop('disabled', false); }); //enable all
        $("#Answer_4").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#Answer_1_Radio").prop("checked", true);
    }
});
$('#NoneOfTheAbove').click(function () {
    if ($('#NoneOfTheAbove').is(':checked')) {
        console.log("None checked");
        $('input:radio[name=CorrectAnswer]').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', false); }); //uncheck all first..
        $("#Answer_4_Radio").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#AllOfTheAbove_Radio").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#AllOfTheAbove").prop('checked', false);
        $("#Answer_4").prop('disabled', true);
        $('#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio').prop("checked", true);
        $('#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio').prop("disabled", false);
    }
    else if ($('#AllOfTheAbove').not(':checked')) {
        console.log("None un checked");
        $('input:radio[name=CorrectAnswer]').each(function () { $(this).prop('checked', false); }); //uncheck all first..
        $('input:radio[name=CorrectAnswer]').each(function () { $(this).prop('disabled', false); }); //enable all
        $("#Answer_4").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#Answer_1_Radio").prop("checked", true);
    }
});

$('#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio').click(function () {
    if ($('#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio').is(':checked')) {
        $("#NoneOfTheAbove").prop("checked", true);
        $("#AllOfTheAbove").prop("checked", false);
        $("#AllOfTheAbove_Radio").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#Answer_4").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#Answer_4_Radio").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});

$('#AllOfTheAbove_Radio').click(function () {
    if ($('#AllOfTheAbove_Radio').is(':checked')) {
        $("#AllOfTheAbove").prop("checked", true);
        $("#NoneOfTheAbove").prop("checked", false);
        $("#NoneOfTheAbove_Radio").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#Answer_4").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#Answer_4_Radio").prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```